# MPMusicPlayerControllerMutableQueue insert an Apple Music song not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-musickit

So I have been trying to use the MusicKit APIs for a few days now. I have been attempting to use the [MPMusicPlayerApplicationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayerapplicationcontroller) and [MutableQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontrollermutablequeue) APIs.

I have queue initialized already using `setQueue(with: [String])` with an array of store identifiers for Apple Music songs. Then I want to allow the user to reorder the songs in the queue. I use the following code to attempt that.

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer

musicPlayerController.perform(queueTransaction: { queue in 

  let afterItem = queue.items.first(where: { $0.playbackStoreID == predecessorId })
  let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: [newItemId])
  queue.insert(descriptor, after: afterItem)

}) { (queue, error) in

  // Completion for when items' position update
  if error != nil {
    print(error!)
  }
}
```

The code above works as expected if `afterItem` is nil (i.e. the song is correctly inserted at the front of the queue). However, if `afterItem` is not nil, nothing happens. The queue stays the exact same as if no insert happened and there is no error provided in the completion handler. This problem happens regardless of whether the song being inserted is already in the queue or not.

Am I attempting modifying the queue incorrectly?

Comment: So if you log the `queue` before and after, it stays the same? I'm just curious how we know that "nothing happens". I'm not doubting you (this whole API is horribly buggy), just curious.

Comment: @matt yes, when logging the queue it is the same

Comment: @matt I just checked again to verify. The all the media items are the same before and after and the order is the same. Some of the media items in the after queue are different objects then the before queue but they have the same contents (storeId, artist, title, etc.) The queues are also different objects.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm this. It's a clear bug. Not just Apple Music; it's `queue.insert` no matter what kind the songs are. Please do file a bug report on this.

Comment: A further bug is that even if `insert` is `nil`, the `queue` in the completion handler does not reflect the change in the queue.

Comment: Are you able to report if this bug was filed and/or fixed? Thanks!

Comment: @matt  Did you find any solution?, still facing same bug, completion handler is not getting called for perform(queueTransaction)

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

If you want the queue to be mutated.

You need to return the query

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer

musicPlayerController.perform(queueTransaction: { queue in 

  let afterItem = queue.items.first(where: { $0.playbackStoreID == predecessorId })
  let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: [newItemId])

  //return the modification here.
  return queue.insert(descriptor, after: afterItem)

}) { (queue, error) in

  // Completion for when items' position update
  if error != nil {
    print(error!)
  }
}
```