# Rearrange MediaPlayer Music Queue [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am really struggling to figure something out and I've looked all over the internet and I can't find an answer. As you know, music apps like Spotify and Apple Music itself let the user rearrange the up next queue even while the user is listening to a song. I haven't been able to figure out how to do the same. I want to be able to completely rearrange the queue including adding, deleting, and moving around songs in the up next queue. I've tried various ways of doing so such as

```
musicPlayer.setQueue([queue])
```

but this would require me to call `musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()` afterwords to update the queue which would end the current song and initiate the new queue.

I've also tried using

```
musicPlayer.perform(queueTransaction: { (currentQueue) in
    let oldItems = currentQueue.items

    var currentItem: MPMediaItem? = nil
    for (i, item) in oldItems.enumerated() {
        if i == musicPlayer.indexOfNowPlayingItem {
            currentItem = item
            continue
        }

        currentQueue.remove(item)
    }

    currentQueue.insert(queue, after: currentItem)
}, completionHandler: { (newQueue, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("there was an error updating the queue", error)
        return
    }

    print("===  NEW QUEUE  ===")  //insert does not work
    for item in newQueue.items {
        print("  -", item.title ?? "[No Title]")
    }
})
```

but as you may know from this question:
[MPMusicPlayerControllerMutableQueue insert an Apple Music song not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592820/mpmusicplayercontrollermutablequeue-insert-an-apple-music-song-not-working)

the insert after item function of a queue doesn't seem to work (and I've also tried setting item to nil which sometimes removed the current item and set the queue to nothing). I also know about `musicPlayer.prepend([queue])` which will add the new queue after the currently playing item but I would also have to remove the previous queue from memory so the up next queue doesn't end up being over 300 songs long. I've also tried using the `prepend` function inside the queue transaction but sometimes the song would stop in the middle and the music player would set the `nowPlayingItem` to nil. I really hope someone knows the answer to this because I've been having this issue for over 4 days now and I can't seem to find a solution that works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MPMusicPlayerController` (and its related subclasses) makes it very difficult to manage a queue like this seamlessly. If I recall correctly, you are not even able to add duplicate `MPMediaItem` objects to the queue, and tapping on the playing media from Control Center will actually launch the Music app instead of your own. Essentially, your app can only act as a shell to the music playing experience, and the Music app is doing all the heavy-lifting.

Depending on your requirements, you may have another option, albeit with some compromises. The `AVFoundation` framework provides
[`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) and [`AVQueuePlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer), which make it easier to manage a queue and provide more advanced playback options. However, you are limited to playing only downloaded, DRM-free content (i.e. songs from Apple Music will not work).

Set up your player:

```
let audioPlayer = AVQueuePlayer()

// Play next song in queue.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didPlayToEndTime), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

// Recover from failed playback.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(failedToPlayToEndTime(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

// Resume music after interruptions.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption(_:)), name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
```

Insert new items in the queue:

```
let media = MPMediaQuery.songs()
let mediaItem: MPMediaItem = media.items.first!

// MPMediaItem objects stored in iCloud or from Apple Music
// will not have a URL, therefore, they cannot be played.
guard let assetURL: URL = mediaItem.assetURL else { return }

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: assetURL)
playerItem.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
```

In my music player app, I keep an `Array` of media to make really simple to reorder, insert, and remove media, and an index to keep track of the currently-playing track. I then pass the media into `AVQueuePlayer` one or two at a time, so that I don't have to mess with its APIs for inserting/removing media.